# Calculate signed distance between point and rectangle

Tags: geometry, glsl, shader, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to write a function in GLSL that returns the signed distance to a rectangle. The rectangle is axis-aligned. I feel a bit stuck; I just can't wrap my head around what I need to do to make it work.

The best I came up with is this:

```
float sdAxisAlignedRect(vec2 uv, vec2 tl, vec2 br)
{
    // signed distances for x and y. these work fine.
    float dx = max(tl.x - uv.x, uv.x - br.x);
    float dy = max(tl.y - uv.y, uv.y - br.y);
    dx = max(0.,dx);
    dy = max(0.,dy);
    return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
```

Which produces a rectangle that looks like:

[image]

The lines show distance from the rectangle. It works fine but ONLY for distances OUTSIDE the rectangle. Inside the rectangle the distance is a static `0.`.

How do I also get accurate distances inside the rectangle using a unified formula?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this...

```
float sdAxisAlignedRect(vec2 uv, vec2 tl, vec2 br)
{
    vec2 d = max(tl-uv, uv-br);
    return length(max(vec2(0.0), d)) + min(0.0, max(d.x, d.y));
}
```

Here's the [result](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtBGWc), where green marks a positive distance and red negative (code below):

[image]

---

Breakdown:

1. Get the signed distance from x and y borders. `u - left` and `right - u` are the two x axis distances. Taking the maximum of these values gives the signed distance to the closest border. Viewing `d.x` and `d.y` are shown individually in the images below.
2. Combine x and y:

   1. If both values are negative, take the maximum (i.e. closest to a border). This is done with `min(0.0, max(d.x, d.y))`.
   2. If only one value is positive, that's the distance we want.
   3. If both values are positive, the closest point is a corner, in which case we want the length. This can be combined with the above case by taking the length anyway and making sure both values are positive: `length(max(vec2(0.0), d))`.

   These two parts to the equation are mutually exclusive, i.e. only one will produce a non-zero value, and can be summed.

[image][image]

---

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    uv -= 0.5;
    uv *= vec2(iResolution.x/iResolution.y,1.0);
    uv += 0.5;
    float d = sdAxisAlignedRect(uv, vec2(0.3), vec2(0.7));
    float m = 1.0 - abs(d)/0.1;
    float s = sin(d*400.0) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    fragColor = vec4(s*m*(-sign(d)*0.5+0.5),s*m*(sign(d)*0.5+0.5),0,1);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Does the job perfectly.

Comment: @jozxyqk How did you come up with this function?

Comment: @v.shashenko trial and error really. I've updated the answer to go into a bit more detail.